# SonarQube exception even following tutorials

Tags: sonarqube

I've downloaded mysql 5.6 and sonarqube. I'm following the tutorials on SonarQube' site. And I'm getting exceptions when I run SonarQube.
This is my sonar.properties' file:

```
...
sonar.web.host:                           0.0.0.1
sonar.web.port:                           80
sonar.web.context:                        /sonar
...
#----- Credentials
# Permissions to create tables and indexes must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username:                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.password:                       sonar
...
#----- MySQL 5.x
# Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following line to use MySQL
sonar.jdbc.url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
...
```

The following shows my exceptions:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2013-09-16 15:21:04.651:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.11.v20130520
jvm 1    | JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
jvm 1    | gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
jvm 1    | 2013-09-16 15:21:18.395:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.Web
AppContext{/sonar,file:/C:/sonar-3.7/war/sonar-server/},file:/C:/sonar-3.7/war/s
onar-server
jvm 1    | 2013-09-16 15:21:18.700:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED SelectCha
nnelConnector@0.0.0.1:80: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested addres
s: bind
jvm 1    | java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(Sele
ctChannelConnector.java:187)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractCo
nnector.java:316)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(S
electChannelConnector.java:265)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abst
ractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:292)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abst
ractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:
67)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:47)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimple
App.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | 2013-09-16 15:21:18.701:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclip
se.jetty.server.Server@11597f2: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested
address: bind
jvm 1    | java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(Sele
ctChannelConnector.java:187)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractCo
nnector.java:316)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(S
electChannelConnector.java:265)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abst
ractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:292)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abst
ractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:
67)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:47)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimple
App.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.net.BindExc
eption: Cannot assign requested address: bind
jvm 1    | java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(Sele
ctChannelConnector.java:187)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractCo
nnector.java:316)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(S
electChannelConnector.java:265)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abst
ractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:292)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abst
ractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:
67)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:47)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimple
App.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Is there any additional file do I need to change to get things done?

Comment: why would you run at port 80? use an apache to redirect to your sonar. It looks like something is already running at port 80. Next to that, use localhost as host, or use it's fully qualified dns name. Also, I see you're using mysql, did you actually install the tables required for sonar in the mysql?

Comment: @3xil3 Hmm, I didn't found what tables I need to install. About the port, it can be something is running on that. What port number is best for this?

Comment: Any decent standard webserver will run on port 80 by default (not sure what you're using, apache, tomcat, ... if any). I would recommend using the standard 9000 port for sonar (until you get the hang of it). But it's only a guideline. And assuming you already have a mysql running on port 3306, you can use a sample table creation script (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/scripts/database/mysql/create_database.sql). Don't forget to add the additional properties for the jdbc user (sonar.jdbc.username:  sonar and sonar.jdbc.password: sonar) to your sonar properties

Comment: @3xil3 I did these steps since from the beginning.
These are the parameters from web settings:
sonar.web.host:                           127.0.0.1
sonar.web.port:                           9000
sonar.web.context:                        /sonar

And now I'm getting this.
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /. Reason:
Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

Comment: I suspect you don't have a webcontainer running. But this is a different error than the one you described earlier isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, to help you further, I would have to see the full stacktrace

Comment: @3xil3 I don't know what a webcontainer is. Sorry. Can you explain? I'm a beginner on this topic. And I've posted all exceptions I have until now, if this is what you mean.

Comment: A webcontainer is basically responsible for the rendering of pages (and a whole lot of other stuff). In this case, rendering sonar related pages. And after rereading your params. Your sonar should be available on localhost:9000/sonar as you put your web context on /sonar instead of the root /.